# How to check if the new architecture is enabled on react native 0.68?

Tags: react-native

Is there any ways to check if the new architecture of react native 0.68 (Fabric) is correctly enabled on IOS ?

Comment: did you find a way?

Comment: Not yet :/ I don't think there is a way actually...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

if the new architecture is enabled metro will show fabric as true in the terminal. found this from Niclola Corti's Bringing the New React Native Architecture to the OSS Community presentation. he explained about this in the following video. (22:22 minutes)

[Bringing the New React Native Architecture to the OSS Community | Nicola Corti | App.js Conf 2022](https://youtu.be/Q6TkkzRJfUo?t=1342)

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to check from the JS side:

```js
const uiManager = global?.nativeFabricUIManager ? 'Fabric' : 'Paper';

console.log(`Using ${uiManager}`);
```

Output: Either `Using Fabric` or `Using Paper`.